# How should I replace a single character with empty string

Tags: java, string, split, trim

I am trying to replace the "," in the string with an empty string "".
I believe the following code is correct, but when I run it with Eclipse.  It doesn't work.  What's wrong with my code and how should I correct it

```
String fullName = "lastname, firstname", lastName, firstName;

    String[] parts = fullName.split(" ");
    String firstPart = parts[0];
    String secondPart = parts[1];

    if (firstPart.contains(",")) {
        firstPart.replace(",", "");
        firstPart.trim();
        secondPart.trim();
        lastName = firstPart;
        firstName = secondPart;  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Java `String` is immutable, so no function alters the `String` instance, just build a new one:

```
string = string.replace(",","");
```

This applies to every method that should alter the content of the `String` itself in your example.

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.

Comment: Ah I see~  I forgot to assign it to a variable after altering it LOL  Thanks for the info ^_^

Answer (score 4):

changed your code to

```
firstPart = firstPart.replace(",","")
```

You haven't assinged the value that's why

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] names = new String[] { "Frisch, Elliott",
      "Elliott Frisch" };
  for (String fullName : names) {
    String last = "";
    String first = "";
    int p = fullName.indexOf(',');
    if (p > -1) {
      last = fullName.substring(0, p).trim();
      first = fullName.substring(p + 1,
          fullName.length()).trim();
    } else {
      p = fullName.indexOf(' ');
      if (p > -1) {
        first = fullName.substring(0, p).trim();
        last = fullName.substring(p + 1,
            fullName.length()).trim();
      }
    }
    System.out.printf(
        "firstname = '%s', lastname = '%s'\n",
        first, last);
  }
}
```

Which prints my name identically (twice), that is -

```
firstname = 'Elliott', lastname = 'Frisch'
firstname = 'Elliott', lastname = 'Frisch'
```